# cin.get() in a loop

Tags: c++, cin

I was trying to read from standard input. The first line is the number of lines that I will read. The lines that I read next will be printed again. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        char a[10];
        cin.get (a, 10);
        cout << "String: " << a << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it and give number of lines, the program exits. I haven't figured out what's going on, so I've decided to ask it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it should behave like you says..try once more.

Comment: tried again - same bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixing formatted and unformatted input is fraught with problems. In your particular case, this line:

```
std::cin >> n;
```

consumes the number you typed, but leaves the `'\n'` in the input stream.

Subsequently, this line:

```
cin.get (a, 10);
```

consumes no data (because the input stream is still pointing at `'\n'`). The next invocation also consumes no data for the same reasons, and so on.

The question then becomes, "How do I consume the `'\n'`?" There are a couple of ways:

You can read one character and throw it away:

```
cin.get();
```

You could read one whole line, regardless of length:

```
std::getline(std::cin, some_string_variable);
```

You could ignore the rest of the current line:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

As a bit of related advice, I'd never use `std::istream::get(char*, streamsize)`. I would always prefer: `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `cin.get()` before `cin.get(a, 10)` will solve your problem because it will read the remaining endline in the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to know this when you are using cin : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/